# Displaying a specific folder of photos in the Android Gallery App

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I'm looking to display a specific folder of images in an app so that the user can browse through them.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://sdcard/Pictures/Album"), "image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

This seems to display all photos on the phone instead of the images I have in this album.  How can I change this code so that the user can browse through images in a specific folder using the gallery app? The idea behind this is not so that the user can choose an image like I've seen in many examples on here but just simply to browse the images.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
+ "/myFolder/");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(root);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, it produces an exception saying it is unable to intantiate android.app.application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.example.test.